# How do i calculate amount of identic elements in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Have a (very long) list, with this structure:

```
li1 = [[1.4, b][1.5, a][1.6, c][1,4, b][1.7,c][1.4, a][1.6,c]]
```

I want to write a loop that calculate amount of elements `li1[i][0`]` with identical value, and put this information in a new list, like this:

```
li2 = [[1.4, 3][1.5, 1][1.6, 2][1.7, 1]]
```

The problem for me is that i do not know what value, or how many different values, i'm searching for..

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import Counter
a, b, c = 'abc'
li1 = [[1.4, b], [1.5, a], [1.6, c], [1.4, b], [1.7, c], [1.4, a], [1.6, c]]
sorted(Counter(x[0] for x in li1).items())
```

(`map` `list` onto this if you desperately want a list of lists.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you only care about the first value of the list, the first step is to extract it from each of the sublists (which should be [tupels](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples), by the way).

```
>>> a,b,c = 'abc'
>>> li1 = [[1.4, b], [1.5, a], [1.6, c], [1,4, b], [1.7, c], [1.4, a], [1.6, c]]
>>> firsts = map(lambda sublist: sublist[0], li1)
```

[`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) calls its first argument with element of the second argument. Since the first argument here is an [anonymous function (lambda)](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) that returns the first element of its argument, the value of firsts is now a list of these first elements:

```
>>> firsts
[1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1, 1.7, 1.4, 1.6]
```

Alternatively, you can also use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to write the same thing in a different way:

```
>>> firsts = [sublist[0] for sublist in li1]
>>> firsts
[1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1, 1.7, 1.4, 1.6]
```

The result of map (in Python 2) and a list comprehension is a list which is stored in memory. This is no problem for our small list `li1`, but can become one for large input lists. Since we only want to count the values once, we don't really need to store them, and can therefore use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) (which "computes" each value in time):

```
>>> first = (sublist[0] for sublist in li1)
```

`firsts` is now a generator object from which we can get the first values.

Now, onto the **counting**. Fortunately, Python 2.6+ provides a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#counter-objects) class, which we can use:

```
>>> import collections
>>> counter = collections.Counter(firsts)
>>> counter.most_common()
[(1.4, 2), (1.6, 2), (1.5, 1), (1.7, 1), (1, 1)]
```

Note that the result is expressed as tupels, which is probably what you want anyways. If you really need a list (for example because you want to append something to the elements), use `map` to make a list out of each tuple:

```
>>> map(list, counter.most_common())
[[1.4, 2], [1.6, 2], [1.5, 1], [1.7, 1], [1, 1]]
```

In summary, the short way to write it all:

```
import collections
a,b,c = 'abc'
li1 = [[1.4, b], [1.5, a], [1.6, c], [1,4, b], [1.7, c], [1.4, a], [1.6, c]]
li2 = collections.Counter(sublist[0] for sublist in li1).most_common()
```

Comment: This simply with `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` and doesn't come close to what OP is asking for (counting duplicates).

Comment: -1 Read again, carefully. That still doesn't do what OP asks for. It simply erases completely duplicate tuples, instead of counting duplicate first items.

Comment: @delnan Updated with a solution that does indeed count, including some explanation as to how and why it works, and using `most_common` instead of `items` to get a result sorted by occurence.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> li1 = [[1.4, 'b'],[1.5, 'a'],[1.6, 'c'],[1.4, 'b'],[1.7,'c'],[1.4, 'a'],[1.6,'c']]
```

First, we create a dictionary with keys like `(1.4,'b')` and values denoting the number of that key elements in the initial list:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for el in li1:
    el = el[0]
    d[el] = d.get(el,0) + 1
```

So, the dictionary looks like:

```
>>> d
{1.5: 1, 1.4: 3, 1.7: 1, 1.6: 2}
```

Also, note, that `d.get` is used. Because initially the dictionary contains no elements, so get returns `0` when there is no element (the second argument of `get`). There are other techniques to achieve this behavior: you may use `DefalutDict` or `Counter` as used in the other answer.

Then we use the dictionary to create the necessary list:

```
>>>[[key,value] for key,value in d.items()]
[[1.5, 1], [1.4, 3], [1.7, 1], [1.6, 2]]
```